# I-130 or Fiance petition

Tags: usa, marriage, mexican-citizens

Is it faster for a U.S citizen to get married in Mexico and then do the I-130, or to go through a Fiancé(e) petition?

Comment: Faster to what? Faster to be in the US physically? Or faster to become a permanent resident?

Comment: Does the one of you who is Mexican have an existing tourist (or other) visa to visit the USA?

Answer (score 2):

USCIS has a [pretty decent page](https://egov.uscis.gov/cris/processingTimesDisplay.do;jsessionid=abcWmDmmOZgyY7wxO935u) showing current processing times.  Depending on where you have to submit your application for either one processing times may vary.

Long story short I would consult an immigration lawyer before doing one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

Once your fiancee enters on K-1 visa, he/she will need to file AOS after the marriage to change status to permanent resident. That would end up being almost an identical process to getting the K-1 visa, which means you'll go through basically the same process twice, sequentially.

If you marry in Mexico and apply for IR-1 visa you'll only go through the process once.